# insert a link in a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hyperlink

I have a script where people click on 'call us' and the number appears and an GA event is send.

Is it possible to link the number to a tel:-link so you can call the number on a mobile?

I tried to insert an ID, but the number isn't clickable then on a phone.

Thanks for any answers,
Dav

This is the script:

```
function ipTrackButton(){
    if(window.jQuery){
        var $ = jQuery;

      var phonenumber = '+31 (0)20 - 679 62 22',
            holder = $('#text-5 > .textwidget'),
            newHTML = 'T: <span id="ipCallButton">Bel ons | Call us</span><br>E: <a href="mailto:info@pvhadvocaten.nl">info@pvhadvocaten.nl</a>',
            body = $('body');

        //Inject styles
        var style = '#ipCallButton { background-color:#eaeaea;padding:5px 8px;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline; } #ipCallButton.ipClicked { text-decoration:none;cursor:default; } ';

        body.append('<style>'+style+'</style>');

        //Set new content
        holder.html(newHTML);

        //Set event
        body.on('click', '#ipCallButton:not(.ipClicked)', function(){
            var _this = $(this);
            _this.html(phonenumber);
            _this.addClass('ipClicked');

            //Send event
            ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Click', 'Telefoonnummer');
        });
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(ipTrackButton, 50);
    }
}

ipTrackButton();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code's problem is that at no point do you create a `<a href="tel:...">` element. All you do is set the element's `innerHTML` to the phone number which isn't clickable.

You'll have to actually insert the `<a>` element:

```
body.on('click', '#ipCallButton:not(.ipClicked)', function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.append($('<a href="tel:' + phonenumber + '">' + phonenumber + '</a>'));
    _this.addClass('ipClicked');
    //Send event
    ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Click', 'Telefoonnummer');
});
```

To be honest I think a better solution would be to add the `<a>` directly in the HTML and hide it with CSS until clicked. You don't really need JavaScript for much of what you're doing:

```js
function ipTrackButton(){
    if(window.jQuery){
        var $ = jQuery;
        var body = $('body');

        //Set event
        body.on('click', '#ipCallButton:not(.ipClicked)', function(){
            var _this = $(this);
            _this.addClass('ipClicked');
            // removed: send ga event
       });
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(ipTrackButton, 50);
    }
}

ipTrackButton();
```

```css
#ipCallButton:not(.ipClicked) .afterclick {
    display: none;
}
#ipCallButton.ipClicked .beforeclick {
    display: none;
}
/* copied */
#ipCallButton { background-color:#eaeaea;padding:5px 8px;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline; } #ipCallButton.ipClicked { text-decoration:none;cursor:default; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
T: <span id="ipCallButton">
  <span class="beforeclick">Bel ons | Call us</span>
  <span class="afterclick">
      <a href="tel:+31 (0)20 - 679 62 22">+31 (0)20 - 679 62 22</a>
</span><br>
E: <a href="mailto:info@pvhadvocaten.nl">info@pvhadvocaten.nl</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, your solution gives the text and the number at the same time in Chrome on my desktop; the number is clickable. On my iPhone only the number appears but it still isn't clickable. Your other solution looks promising, but I was hoping to fix the current script.

Comment: @davisra Just tried the snipped in Chrome and it works for me. Looks like you'll need a better understanding of why this is happening before trying to integrate my solution.